# extend UserManager to search User by relation (symfony3)

Tags: doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle, symfony3.x

I installed FOSUserbundle and HWI Oauth bundle.
My problem is: I want to access data from my user entity that is stored in a relation. I'd like to access the data from the fields social_network_slug and social_identifier from UserInSocialNetworks within the FOSUserProvider.
The idea was, that one user can have more that one social network logins. (1:n)- When I log in with my google/facebook etc login, I want to check the table user_in_social_networks if the Id with the social network already exists.

```
/*
 * This is the User class, depending on fos_userBundle
 */

namespace AppBundle\Entity\Registration;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * One User can have many social networks
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserInSocialNetworks", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $socialnetworks; ....
```

the Entity Class to store all User's social media logins:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity\Registration;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;



/**
 * UserInSocialNetworks
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_in_social_networks")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Registration\UserInSocialNetworksRepository")
 */
class UserInSocialNetworks
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many Socialnetwork Logins have one User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Registration\User", inversedBy="socialnetworks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="social_network_slug", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $socialNetworkSlug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="social_identifier", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $socialIdentifier;
```

The extended FOSUBUserProvider class:

```
    <?php
    namespace AppBundle\Entity\Registration;

    use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\OAuth\Response\UserResponseInterface;
    use HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\FOSUBUserProvider as BaseClass;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


    class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
    {
    /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
        {
            // get user_id and socialnetworkname from response
            $userIdInSocialNetwork = $response->getUsername();
            $socialnetwork = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
// Here I'd like to search for an existing $userIdInSocialNetwork
```

What I checked since now: I can't access the entitymanager in FOSUBUserProvider class, and I can't search that way:

```
$user = $this->userManager->findUserBy(array(
                'socialIdentifier' => $userIdInSocialNetwork,
                'social_network_slug' => $socialnetwork)
```

because it's a relation.
Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have extended `FOSUBUserProvider` i assume you have defined a new service for this, If so then you can pass doctrine's entity manager to your class `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager`. Following [`HWIOAuthBundle`](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) documentation for [`FOSUserBundle`](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/4-integrating_fosub.md) you can pass entity manager as

```
services:
    my.custom.user_provider:
        class:        MyBundle\Security\Core\User\MyFOSUBUserProvider
        arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager', { facebook: facebook_id }, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

And then in your class you can use this service as

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
//.... other use statements

class FOSUBUserProvider extends BaseClass
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, array $properties, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct($userManager, $properties); /* pass dependencies to parent */
    }

    public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Registration\UserInSocialNetworks')->findBy(....);

        /* Do your stuff here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fast and very correct answer. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Get error on my implementation but resolve this by adding quote to the third argument like bellow:

```
services:
my.custom.user_provider:
    class:        MyBundle\Security\Core\User\MyFOSUBUserProvider
    arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager', { facebook: facebook_id }, '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

Comment: This looks exactly like M Khalid Junaids answer.